# Check if a 2d matrix is square in python

Tags: python

The task is to check if a 2D matrix is square. My code works with testing 2d lists in the form [[a],[b],[c],[d]], returning True if it is square and False if not. However, when submitting to the automatic tester, it says that it expects true and gets returned false.

I do not know why this is happening and would greatly appreciate any help.

```
def is_square(mat):
    i = 0
    while(i < len(mat)):
        if(len(mat[i]) != len(mat)):
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
```

Comment: I do not see any issues- make sure the function is actually being called, and that the tests want a boolean and not `"True"`/`"False"` strings.

Comment: can you explain about your automatic tester function?

Comment: Also, you can make use of some language features to simplify your code. For example, using `for row in mat:` instead of a while loop, or even a one-liner using `all()` : `all(len(row) == len(mat) for row in mat)`.

Comment: The code seems fine, please post the automatic tester.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, regarding the tester function, we submit the code and it is automatically tested with a given matrix, i.e. I don't get to see the matrix that is being tested. This is only a small part of the task, which is to test if the matrix is a lorentz transformation, which must be square amongst other things. My concern is that the matrix the test function gives is not in the form of a 2d list, but I don't see what else it could be.

Comment: It might be a numpy array. You might re-write your function for this case and test again.

Comment: So it turns out is was a numpy matrix, which you cannot use len() on, thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `all` returns `true` if all of the elements of an iteration are `true`.

```
def is_square(mat):
    return all([len(i)==len(mat) for i in mat])
```